# Calculate off sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

Can anyone explain what's wrong with the syntax on the line that starts If DBSheet.Range?

Also, I know there is a way to do the calculations "off the sheet" and then spit them back into the sheet? I have an idea on how to do this using .formula and .value, but i am not quite sure how. Can someone explain how i can do this so my calculation is efficient. Thanks!

```
Dim DBSheet As Worksheet, InSheet As Worksheet, ExSheet As Worksheet, i As Long

Set DBSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("db_main")
Set InSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("interface")
Set ExSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("export")




    For i = 2 To 40000

        If DBSheet.Range("S" & i) <= InSheet.Range("C20") And DBSheet.Range("S" & i) = InSheet.Range("O15") Then

            ExSheet.Range("A" & i) = DBSheet.Range("N" & i)



        End If

    Next i
```

Comment: As to the first part of your question, seems to work OK for me.

Comment: Can you please clarify your issue? Which part of the code you're having trouble, what error do you get. If it is not producing the expected output, explain what you want to achieve. As is now, you're question is unclear.

Comment: I'm getting a runtime error 13 on the line "If DBSheet.Range("S"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem appears to be a type error on your comparison line which also is the first time you reference a Range.

First, verify that the data in those cells is of the datatypes you want (numbers I assume). Second, in my experience Excel will almost always treat ws.Range(...) as a range object which would throw an error in your inequality because it is not just the value you are looking for. You should change that to ws.Range("S" & i).Value or ws.Cells(i, 19).Value. Additionally you probably need to convert that to a number from a string for your comparison using Val() or CDbl() or CInt(). So we have options like:

```
Val(ws.Range("S" & i).Value)
CDbl(ws.Cells(i, 19).Value)
```

As far as off sheet calculations, if you are referring to using another worksheet for calculations, you would do basically what you are doing right now just with a 4th worksheet object. If you are referring to calculations in memory, it would be something like...

```
Dim areaCircle As Double
Dim radius As Double, circumference As Double
Dim ratioOfCircumferenceToArea As Double
radius = CDbl(ws.Cells(i, 19).Value)
areaCircle = radius^2 * 3.14159
circumference = 2 * 3.14159 * radius
ratioOfCircumferenceToArea = circumference / area
```

Without more information about what you are trying to calculate "off sheet," I can just give you these general cases.

Comment: Good answer Mark, but for the life of me I cannot get his code to fail (runtime error 13) no matter what values I use.  I must be missing something.